# Web Application Password Security

Tags: java, security, properties, configuration

My company has a Java Web Application with the database password stored in a properties file and we need to secure the password. I've googled and found the Jasypt solution, but in my mind that doesn't really solve the problem because that requires another password to feed to the application and I don't know how to secure that password.

The main suggestion for Jasypt is to feed the password in as an environment variable, which means that in the best case scenario I would be starting the application like:

```
./myApp -D password=myPasswordDontHackPlz
```

which isn't secure because you can see the password when you do

```
ps -ef | grep myApp
```

We also can't feed the password in when it needs it (via a the web or something) because it essentially decides when it needs the password, and it needs it pretty often.

Is there any solution to this or am I asking for some magical solution that doesn't exist? I don't like Jasypt because it seems to me to essentially just be obfuscation, and I'm not after obfuscation i'm looking for true security here.

Comment: "an environment variable" meaning `password=myPasswordDontHackPlz ./myApp`, isn't it? That should keep it out of the command line, I think. http://mosh.mit.edu/#build-instructions reports that "a running process's environment variables are not readable by other users" "on GNU/Linux, OS X, and FreeBSD."

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you put the password in a properties file which is only readable by the user that runs the web application?  The web application will need to know the root password at some stage, so obviously you want it to be able to read/use it.  What you want is that noone else should be able to read it, and protecting the file will do it.

This is all assuming that you need to externalize your password.  You could hardcode it into the application if you wanted to make it harder to get at, but someone with access to the JAR can always decompile your classes.

Answer (score 0):

I am just wondering - storing a root database password is a bad idea in general. But then again, when someone actually manages to get access to that file on the server, how safe is your database anyway?

Would the password still show up if you created a shell script and run it instead?

```
#!/bin/bash
./myApp -D password=myPasswordDontHackPlz
```